# How to convert Current Account In to Partner Account

Tags: account, account-management

i am trying to convert an account in  to partner account.i am following link https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=partner_portal_creating_partner_accounts.htm&language=en_US .i created an account but after creation its not showing any button or link labeled as Manage External Account as you can see in screenshot 
[image]

please guideline how to convert an account into Partner account.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a partner portal or community?

Comment: no,i didn't created any partner portal or community.

Comment: I've not created partner accounts, but I don't believe you can create partner users without a partner portal. Partner users were mentioned in the same reference you gave. You need to have partner licenses to do the latter.